# How to add a "Custom Label" to iOS AddressBook programmatically?

Tags: iphone, label, addressbook

When manually adding a contact's phone / IMS in the iOS AddressBook, you can add a Custom Label instead of "Home", "Work", "Other" * (in IMS).

How to create "Custom Label" in AddressBook programmatically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had this exact same question. I couldn't find an answer so I just tried the guess and check method. The following code seems to work:

```
CFErrorRef error = NULL; 
ABAddressBookRef iPhoneAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef newPerson = ABPersonCreate();
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, @"Jane", &error);
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty, @"Smith", &error);

const CFStringRef customLabel = CFSTR( "mylabel" );

//phone
ABMutableMultiValueRef multiPhone = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone, @"1-444-444-444", kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone, @"1-333-333-333", kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, NULL);            
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone, @"1-666-666-666", kABOtherLabel, NULL);        
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone, @"1-555-555-555", customLabel, NULL); 
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty, multiPhone,nil);
CFRelease(multiPhone);

ABAddressBookAddRecord(iPhoneAddressBook, newPerson, &error);
ABAddressBookSave(iPhoneAddressBook, &error);

if (error != NULL)
{   
    NSLog(@"Error!");   
}
```

If you check the address book, you will see a phone number with a custom label: mylabel

Thanks to: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404975/what-are-the-tags-around-default-iphone-address-book-people-phone-number-labels)

And to: [this blog](http://www.modelmetrics.com/tomgersic/iphone-programming-adding-a-contact-to-the-iphone-address-book/)